# apache/lucenenet Unable to limit memory usage - RAMBufferSizeMB, RAMPerThreadHardLimitMB, and MaxBufferedDocs in IndexWriterConfig has no effect

Tags: memory, memory-management, lucene, ram, lucene.net

Note that I've also posted an issue on GitHub on the repo: https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/issues/784

I'm running the latest Lucene .NET versions:

- Lucene.Net 4.8.0-beta00016
- Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common 4.8.0-beta00016

I'm doing the following:

```cs
            using var analyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();
            using var directory = FSDirectory.Open(IndexPath);
            var config = new IndexWriterConfig(LuceneVersion, analyzer)
            {
                OpenMode = OpenMode.CREATE, // Use OpenMode.CREATE to overwrite, or OpenMode.APPEND to just open
                RAMPerThreadHardLimitMB = 100,
                RAMBufferSizeMB = 100,
            };
            using var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
            
            // Write index to disk
            writer.AddDocuments(productDocuments);
            writer.AddDocuments(productCategoryDocuments);
            writer.AddDocuments(productTypeDocuments);
            writer.AddDocuments(productLineDocuments);
            writer.Commit();
```

As soon as writer.AddDocuments() is called, the memory consumption grows a lot.
You can see the sudden increase in the Diagnostic Tool in visual studio:

[image]

Running it multiple times keeps increasing the memory usage up to 3GB (on my machine), at which point it doesn't grow any longer. And these 3GB are never released again. The program doesn't crash, and it stops acquiring memory.

I want to limit how much memory Lucene can use, but using `RAMBufferSizeMB` and `RAMPerThreadHardLimitMB` seems to have no effect at all.

I tried flushing as well, which had no effect, and I tried calling Dispose() which also had no effect.

I've also tried setting `MaxBufferedDocs` to 1000, still no limit to RAM usage.

Have I missed something in the documentation? Is there a way to limit RAM usage of the Lucene .NET IndexWriter?

Answer (score 0):

To future developers having memory consumption issues with Lucene.Net:

Try writing one document at a time with `writer.AddDocument()` rather than `writer.AddDocuments()`.

`writer.AddDocument()` handles memory much better than `writer.AddDocuments()`.

Also calling `writer.Commit()` more will flush memory more often, and the Garbage Collector can keep the memory consumption lower.

My experiments with Lucene in a Console Application can be seen here: https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/issues/784